# Confused About Member Access Train in Class?

Tags: c++, class, syntax, member

I have the following class:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Locker{


public:

int lockerId;

string renterName;

double monthlyRent;

// The variable is true when the locker is a vip locker
//if the locker is a regular locker then this variable is set to false

bool isVip;

bool isRentOverdue;

Locker(){};

Locker(int id, string name, double rent, bool vip=0, bool overdue=0);

bool operator==(Locker const &other);
 };
```

**EDIT: LOCKER NODE CLASS**

```
class LockerNode{
public:

Locker objLocker;
LockerNode *next;


LockerNode(){
    next=0;
};

LockerNode(Locker e, LockerNode *ptr=0){
    objLocker=e;
    next=ptr;
}
  };
```

and implementation:

```
#include <sstream>
#include "Locker.h"

#include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 Locker::Locker(int id, string name, double rent, bool vip, bool overdue){
lockerId=id; renterName=name; monthlyRent=rent; isVip=vip; isRentOverdue=overdue;
 }

 bool Locker::operator==(Locker const &other){
if(lockerId==other.lockerId && renterName==other.renterName && monthlyRent==other.monthlyRent && isVip==other.isVip && isRentOverdue==other.isRentOverdue)
    return true;
else return false;
 }
```

I have the following code in a function, trying to track both the number of objects in a linked list, and perform some operations on them based on how many their are and their properties. I am passing in `e` which is a newly created object. If an object has property vip = true, I need to place it ahead of other non-vip objects, unless there is already a vip object, in which case it goes just behind it. Hence, the following code:

```
int count = 0;
LockerNode *p = head;

for(;p!=0;count++, p=p->next) {

    if(count == 1) {
        if (e.isVip) {
            if(p->isVip) // !!!!!!!!!Issue here!!!!!!!!!!
        }

    }
```

I checked the parameter fine to determine if it is vip or not. However, I am unsure how to check the current element I am at in the list for the same. My above effort on the line in question has not worked. I'm a little confused as to the syntax. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where is your locker Node class? problem could be there...

ok try replacing this :

```
 if(p->isVip) // !!!!!!!!!Issue here!!!!!!!!!!
```

with:

```
if (p->objLocker.isVip) {//true/false for this node
```

p is a pointer accesing his members is with->
but objlocker is not a pointer accesing his members is with a "."

Comment: Apologies, neglected to include it. See original post in a second.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the clarifying sentence. I think I still need e.isVip, though. Basically, e.isVip checks if the CURRENT locker object is VIP or not (i.e. the one I am trying to find a place for). p is a pointer that searches the list for lockers already in place.

Comment: yes i see now i deleted somthing i shouldent importen thing as that u got the idea and u can solve the problem urself now